# What is the difference between Adobe Photoshop CS vs Adobe Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Adobe site there is a Adobe Creative suit CS6 and Adobe Creative Cloud.What is the main difference between the two?

Comment: One is a cloud product and requires a subscription the other requires a single payment.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Adobe Creative Cloud Bundle that includes everything Adobe has to offer. Within both Photoshop and Illustrator, I can't find a single difference between them and their desktop/CS counterparts. The other applications are the same as well, but your question focused on Photoshop.

One other thing is the CC apps requires an internet connection to 'check in' occasionally with Adobe. I'm not sure what happens if your internet is down during this period, but you may lose access to these apps until they are allowed to connect to the internet. I haven't verified this yet.